# how to make a collapsible column in html code

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please see the image below.

[Table diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZZiP.png)

By default the view of the table should be alike Table 1 (with + sign in beginning). 
When we click on + sign, rows should expand in the next  and the sign should change to –(minus).
Similarly when we click  on – sign,  should collapse again and + sign should appear now.

I have pasted below the code for the above but could not figure out what changes needs to be made for this functionality. Can someone please help on it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=en_US">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    tr.even {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    tr.odd {
      background-color: #EEEEEE;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="5%"></td>
        <td>
          <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
              <tr style="font-size:16px; background-color:lightgray;">
                <th><a name="table">&nbsp;</a>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="odd">
                <td>+ Country</td>
                <td>
                  <p>India</p>
                  <p>Europe</p>
                  <p>Asia</p>
                  <p>Russia</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td width="5%"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "rows should expand in the next". Also, do you have any javascript you could provide us that you were working with? Thanks!

Comment: I  meant that one pressing + sign in column 1, the expansion of values is happening in column 2. This can  be seen in the table picture as well.

Comment: Right now i am not using any js file.  Can you please help.

Comment: You tagged the question with the [tag:jquery] tag, so I assume that's what you will be working with. If you want to use a listener, I would recommend using _selector_.on('click', _function_); to call a function that toggles the height of your column or hides all but the first `<p></p>`. Documentation on that function can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You can also avoid jquery by using the inline onclick event, but it depends on your preference.

Comment: Can you please help in adding this change in my code. I need it asap.